# vertically align div red

Tags: html, css, alignment

Could someone please have a look at my jsfiddle and see if you can make the red div vertically align in the middle and get the red div to be centred as well. You will have to make the div that contains the red div a certain height

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Xgr3k/17/)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row1">
        <div>
            <div style="height:200px; width:725px; background-color:red; margin:0px auto">A</div>

        </div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row2">
        <div>B</div>
        <div>C</div>
    </div>
</div>

html, body {
    height:100%; margin:0px; padding:0px    

}
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display:table;    
    position: relative;
}
.row1 {
    display:table-row;
    max-height: 425px;
    background: pink;
}
.row1 div {
    display:table-cell;
    width:100%;
}
.row2 {
    display:table-row;
    height: 100%;
}
.row2 div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    float:left;
    background: green;
}
.row2 div + div {
    background: aqua;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
}
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
    .row1 {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .row1 div + div {
        display: none;
    }
    .row2 div + div {
        width:50%
    }
    .row2 div {
        width: 50%;
    }
    .row2 div + div {
        position: static;
    }
}
```

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/VL5dr/

Comment: No the red div need to be centered by it's parent and vertically aligned in the middle

Answer (score 0):

Just a small change makes your `table-cell` rule apply only to the immediate children of what you're calling `table-row`: `.row1 > div` instead of `.row1 div`.  See the update: http://jsfiddle.net/Xgr3k/11/

This fixes your problem except now your aqua colored div is popping up whenever your width > 1024.  That's happening because of your media query and setting that div to `position: static`.  Which I'm not sure you want to do.  But, basically, be careful about how your rules cascade down your DOM.  Good luck :)

Comment: Ok I checked out what you did and made a change in the percent and it works better now but the problem now is when you maximize the area to it's maximum it doesn't align centred how do I fix that. It's almost finished can you help fix it http://jsfiddle.net/Xgr3k/13/

Comment: checkout my last comment and fiddle

Comment: K, this works but that aqua div is gonna cause you problems.  And the way you defined these rules is very hard to think about.  I'd suggest looking at how bootstrap and those kinds of libraries do layouts.  Anyway, good luck: http://jsfiddle.net/Xgr3k/16/